# Not able to import Selenium jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Not able to import Selenium jar files in Eclipse for some reason, while importing first time from quick fixes it works showing no error after saving the program it showing me that import is not working

Below is code:
[image]

Note: The issues arise only for Java projects only

Comment: Embed the image directly into the question instead of an external link which may expire any time.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use maven for the dependency management. Eventhough a quick demo with just a couple of dependecies should be ok in eclipse it is sometimes a pain in the a.
Try rebuilding the project. Build -> Build Project, and check the project setup. Eclipse gives also a error log when sth goes wrong. Have you taken a look at it? Problems View.